# Python code is only saying no when i run it?

Tags: python

I coded this in repl.it but it isn't working. Can anyone tell me why?

```
import random, sys

mynumber = random.randint(1, 31)
month = 0
print("password cracker 1.0")
username = input("Email: ")
year = input("Year that they were born: ")
while True:
    if month == mynumber and year == 2006:
        print("yes")
        print(month)
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print("no")
        month + 1
```

Comment: `year` is a string, not an `int`. `2006 != "2006"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare compatible types. Either

```
int(year) == 2006
```

or

```
year == "2006"
```

The string `"2006"` returned by `input` is not equal to the `int` value `2006`.